# Drupal custom login with a custom URL

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Before I write a few questions I need to said that I tried to made a custom drupal login on a way which is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737229/custom-login-form-in-a-drupal-7

So, that means to override http://example.org/user login page. That doesn't work in my case because I can hide header & footer (because they are built on a different way without using drupal blocks).

Now I turn to a different solution. I create a custom content type 'login' and a custom template file as you can see below:

http://www.will.sx/login

Now I need a drupal log in functionality to integrate in my custom form.

Here is HTML code:

```
  <div id="form-wrapper">
    <form id="login">
        <h1>billing &amp; support</h1>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Type your email">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Type your password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        <a href="#" class="reset-pass">Forgot password?</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now I need a PHP code to make this log in form useful. Every kind of help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it that way you would have to validate your form with [drupal_validate_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_validate_form/7) or else your website will be prone to an [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

However, you can implement a much easier and secure method by creating a whole new page layout for just the user login page that will override the page.tpl.php template by using template_preprocess_page in your template.php file. Copy the following code into template.php:

```
function yourthemename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $url = drupal_get_destination();
    $url = $url['destination'];
    if ($url == 'user/login') {
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] =  "page__user_login";
    }
}
```

Create the file page--user-login.tpl.php in your templates folder.

You can copy and paste your original page.tpl.php code into page--user-login.tpl.php, remove whatever you don't need, and flush the cache.

Answer (score -2):

> I create a custom content type 'login' and a custom template file as you can see below:

Sorry, but this is very bad approach.

I don't understand, why you can't just redefine user login form, but instead of creating custom content type you can create you custom page using hook_menu() (or redefine standard with hook_menu_alter()). Note, that in code of your custom pages you can redefine all Drupal output, if you needs this (just print result, and not return it from page callback).
See api.drupal.org for hooks declaration & examples.

Then, in code of your page callback, just print your form, something like this:

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('my_login_form'));
```

I recommend you to use standard login form form (with id "user_login", just replace 'my_logn_form' in above code to 'user_login'), because drupal login logic isn't simple for repeating.

About creating custom pages: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7